# How to use a RobotFramework keyword in a loop for x amount of selectors?

Tags: robotframework

I have recently started to learn GUI automation with Robot Framework and I bumped into my first problem.
I am trying to make a script that will test all confirmation dialogues on the website. My current solution for this is a custom keyword with all the tests in it, and then I call the keyword for each confirmation dialogue.

```
Test Confirmation Dialogue    ${CD1}
Test Confirmation Dialogue    ${CD2}
Test Confirmation Dialogue    ${CD3}
*
*
*
```

Is there a way to put this in some loop and avoid using the keyword once per confirmation dialogue?

Comment: Using loops might help you out, as explained in the official documentation: https://robocorp.com/docs/languages-and-frameworks/robot-framework/for-loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a loop over all CD variables, and pass each to your keyword:

```
FOR    ${cd}    IN    ${CD1}    ${CD2}   ${CD3}
    Test Confirmation Dialogue  ${cd}
END
```